# Changing order monitor frequency with php?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

is there some nice person, which can write me simple example of how to change order monitor with php script?
I think that in PS is some function for this, but I am new to PS. I want to get the order notifications as soon as possible through the admin panel.  I found the system already got the function on the header of the web.  But it is kind of slow. I thinks it got a timing interval. How can I  change the timing interval?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for file `js/admin/notifications.js`. The line almost at the very bottom is:

```
setTimeout("getPush(1)", 120000);
```

`120000` is the time interval in milliseconds, each 120000 milliseconds (2 minutes) the script will run `getPush` function. You can change it to whatever you want, however, be reasonable, you probably don't want to run it every second.

Comment: Thanks bro! You save my days